# What's wrong with this code? I am new to CodeChef and it is saying that my output is not correct

Tags: c

I am new to CodeChef and I am solving the beginner section in C lang. I wrote the code for problem =>

**You are asked to calculate factorials of some small positive integers.**

Input 
An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of testcases, followed by t lines, each containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100.

Output 
For each integer n given at input, display a line with the value of n!

I am getting the correct output but my code is not getting accepted. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fact(int x) {
    int temp = 1;

    if(x<=1) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    } else {
      for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        temp *= i;
      }   
      printf("%d\n", temp);  
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    int t;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    if(t>=1 && t<=100) {
      while(t--) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n>=1 && n<=100) {
          fact(n);
        }
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Sample input:
4
1
2
5
3

Sample output:
1
2
120
6
```

Comment: Have you tried `100!`?  Do you know what the result should be?

Comment: What do you think is `0!`?

Comment: Spoiler: for n=100, your program should output the number 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000. This is somewhat larger than the maximum value that can be represented by a variable of type `int`.

Comment: I wonder how this can be a beginners exercise since it cannot be solved with standard data types.

Comment: You can only go up to 12! using `int` and 20! using `long long int`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Condition in OP's task is: `1<=n<=100` so the value of 0! doesn't matter - but, as a spoiler, 0! is a non-zero, positive integer, less than 2.

Comment: You need to use a floating-point number for `temp` ('double` is probably best).

Comment: @nielsen `double` is a standard data type that can hold an approximation to 100!

Comment: This is the "practice" section of CodeChef, where [all submissions are available](https://www.codechef.com/status/FCTRL2). Why don't you look at how other people have (or haven't) solved it?

Comment: @Adrian ***which*** approximation of 100! do you suppose will be accepted as a correct answer?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I guess the only one (or one of two) that can be represented by any standard `C` data type.

Comment: @Adrian Approximation is the keyword here. A `double` normally has 53 precision bits which is far from enough to represent 100! exactly. Anyway, you are probably right that the intended solution is with `double`, but do not expect to impress any mathematicians :-).

Comment: @WeatherVane That is a good question since the C standard does not specify the floating-point types properties.

Answer (score 1):

`100!` is around 9e157 and then it cannot be represented by an `int` (even a 64 bits). It cannot even be represented by an `unsigned long long`.

You have to use `double` but you might not get the exact value as a floating point type cannot represent all integer numbers.

If you want to get the exact value, you have to implement your own integer structure or use arrays of integers and implement the multiplication on them.

Comment: You don't need to implement a new data type. The problem isn't all that hard - one solution involves multiplying an array of single digits by a small integer and propogating a carry.

Comment: Yes, the expression "integer type" was badly chosen

Comment: @WeatherVane: Implementing multiplication of an array of digits is implementing a new data type.